# How to find current truststore on disk programatically?

Tags: java, ssl, truststore

Is there any function which tells me what's the current truststore being used in my program. On windows, the default trust store is at JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts.

However, the default can be changed in a variety of ways.

- Using `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` in the command line
- Using `Keystore` class.
- If the program is running on an App Server under which the application runs may set the store path through it's panel.
- If the program is running on Tomcat, then Tomcat settings may change the truststore.

and many other ways.

Is there a programmatic way by which I can find out the disk path of the truststore which is currently active?

Comment: What exactly is the problem younneed to solve?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - sometimes there is no different question behind the question :-)

Comment: Then get the source code for the JDK, and see what the code does.  If you are lucky, there is a log statement telling you what it does, which you can enable in the Java console.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't (this is quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140199/372643)).

In the JSSE API, trusting a certificate isn't actually determined by a trust store, but by a `TrustManager`. Whilst it's often initialised with a keystore (the truststore), this is not necessary. In addition, the [keystores themselves don't have to be files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6157716/372643). There is nothing in the default trust manager API that lets you check where and how a potential trust store was used.

There isn't even anything in the `SSLSocket` that lets you get back to its `SSLSocketFactory`, and nothing there that lets you get back to its originating `SSLContext`, and nothing there that lets you get the trust managers.

Which truststore/trust manager is currently active also depends very much on the application. Nothing tells you in general that the connections an application is making are using the default `SSLContext`, which can be initialised by the `javax.net.ssl.*` system properties. Applications are free to initialise their own `SSLContext`s to create their sockets (this is what Tomcat do for its connectors when you specify certain values).

Since Java 6, the default (current) `SSLContext` can also be changed globally (via `SSLContext.setDefault(...)`.

You can find what's being used by default from the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization). The rest will depend on the documentation of each application. Using `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,trustmanager` may help if you need, but this isn't API access.

(By the way, `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` will set up the keystore for the default key manager, not the trust store.)

Comment: still when  `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,trustmanager` quickly gives you as log `trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\jre\lib\security\cacerts`, it helps (I though I was running java 8)