# Get SSLContext for default system truststore in Java(JSEE)

Tags: java, security, ssl, default

I've been using custom keystore in my program by specifying **javax.net.ssl.keyStore**, **javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword**, **javax.net.ssl.trustStore**, **javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword**. My truststore contains self-signed certificates. Now I want to make some https request(say to https://google.com) and use default jre system trusstore that contains information about different CAs. To make http requests I use OkHttp library. Its client has an option to specify **SslSocketFactory**, but to get it I need to initialise **SSLContext** for default jre truststore. How can I do that?

UPDATE:
The code I went with is

```
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

    // load default jvm keystore
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(
            System.getProperties()
                  .getProperty("java.home") + File.separator
                + "lib" + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                + "cacerts"), "changeit".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

    tmf.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
```

Comment: @EJP, updated question. I put selfsigned certificates there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `javax.net.ssl.*` system properties will affect the default `SSLContext`, the one used by `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()` and the one returned by `SSLContext.getDefault()`, if you haven't used `SSLContext.setDefault(...)` using a custom context, that is.

If you want to keep the ability to use the default truststore for some connections (not not the ones where you use these self-signed certs), you shouldn't use those properties. Instead you should make the other connections use an `SSLContext` built for those self-signed certs. (You can't really [get the default trust store with certainty otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13660336/372643), at least not without using the private API in the JRE.)

Since the library you're using allows you to specify an `SSLSocketFactory`, build one from your custom `SSLContext` when you want to use it. (You can also build one from the default `SSLContext` for the other cases if needed, although that's often implied, if that library resets its settings between connections.)

Answer (score 1):

You use the default trust store by not specifying a different one.  If you omit the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and the `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` parameters, you will use the default values. (Which, for reference, are `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` and `changeit` (yes, really)).

Comment: You don't need to specify the truststore password at all actually.